# Shopify API: Importing a JSON formatted list of products through a private app

Tags: ajax, json, api, rest, shopify

Essentially I have a file with a list of products I would like to add to my shopify store, I'm fairly certain it's formatted correctly although if it isn't please tell me what to fix. I was wondering how using a POST request through a private app I could get these onto my store. The file looks like this:

```
{
"product": {
    "title": "TITLE HERE",
    "body_html": "DESCRIPTION HERE",
    "vendor": "VENDOR HERE",
    "product_type": "PRODUCT TYPE HERE",
    "variants": {
        "option1": "Default",
        "price": "PRICE HERE"
    },
    "images": {
        "src": "LINK TO IMAGE HERE"
    }
},
"product": {
    "title": "TITLE HERE",
    "body_html": "DESCRIPTION HERE",
    "vendor": "VENDOR HERE",
    "product_type": "PRODUCT TYPE HERE",
    "variants": {
        "option1": "Default",
        "price": "PRICE HERE"
    },
    "images": {
        "src": "LINK TO IMAGE HERE"
    }
},
"product": {
    "title": "TITLE HERE",
    "body_html": "DESCRIPTION HERE",
    "vendor": "VENDOR HERE",
    "product_type": "PRODUCT TYPE HERE",
    "variants": {
        "option1": "Default",
        "price": "PRICE HERE"
    },
    "images": {
        "src": "LINK TO IMAGE HERE"
    }
},
```

and so on... 
This file is named "products.json". Is there any POST request that would allow me to just submit this file, or would I have to process and break it down somehow and feed it to the API using PHP or Ruby...I spent the greater part of a day extracting all 500+ products out of a corrupted MySQL CMS backup and getting them all cleaned up in JSON (using PHP and some regex), so a pain free solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not valid json, you have multiple `product` keys maybe you should use an array instead.

Comment: @Musa I feel like if I changed the `product` key to anything else the shopify API won't recognize the format and throw an error. I tried to emulate the format found in the docs [here](http://api.shopify.com/product.html#create). Maybe you could take a look and let me know how I should format it.

Comment: you can leave the 'product' as a key, you just need to change the json to be in an array format: {["product":...],["product":...]...}

Comment: @ftom2 Ok I can do that using `json_decode` in PHP, but can an associative array have multiple elements with the same key? How does that work? Sorry if it's a dumb question, I don't do this type of stuff normally...

Comment: All the JSON strings contain only a single `product` object. So it looks like you can only have 1 product but it can have multiple variants, also what @ftom2 suggests will give you a different format than what it shows in the link.

Comment: it will be an array of arrays (or array of product objects if you will), where the first array is index based (0,1,2...) and the second one has product as key so you'll do something like $arr[0]['product']. just print_r the array and see what you get

Comment: Hmm, some conflicting ideas here. So if I `json_encode` this and store it in a PHP variable, the variable will contain an array of arrays, where the "outside" array contains indices 0....n-1, where n-1 is the number of products, and each index stores an associative array within it storing a `product` array, which stores the components etc...Is that correct? And once I have this array of arrays, how do I POST it to shopify's API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot submit multiple products to be created at once, they need to be submitted individually. The docs you already linked to explain all the available API endpoints and the format for the data.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to upload an individual product using PHP cURL and keep getting `{"errors":"Error"}` as a response. This is what I'm trying to post: `{"product":{"title":"PRODUCT TITLE","body_html":"BODY HERE","vendor":"VENDOR HERE","product_type":"TYPE HERE","variants":{"option1":"Default","price":"100.00"},"images":{"src":"IMAGE URL"}}}` . I do this using this PHP function: `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true); curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($cleanarray[0]));` (and all the other stuff like `curl_init` and `curl_close` etc... I have no idea what I'm doing wrong....

Comment: Can you try the most basi creat and see if that works? {
  "product": {
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard",
    "tags": "Barnes & Noble"
  }
}
Also, did you specify accepts and content type headers?

Comment: It works now, I wasn't sending a content type header. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can store these products in database and by creating a connection from database you can add multiple products at a time by defining one array and its value will be fetched from database.

Comment: Could you please link some documentation on how to create this connection to the database?